# Space does not get blue underline when linkified in Google documents

Tags: google-docs, links

I want to add a hyperlink on a string that contains a space:

[image]

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Why doesn't the space get underlined in blue, like it does in some other parts of Google document

[image]

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been fixed.

Example:

[image]